# Setting UL to be visible from code-behind not working

Tags: asp.net

This is weird.  It's got to be something stupid.

I have the following in my page (it's located in a **user control** in my page)

```
<div id="notifications" class="notificationsContainer" runat="server">
    <ul id="notificationsList" visible="false" runat="server"></ul>
</div>
```

And the last thing that's run in the .ascx.cs's Page_Load is this line of code:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationsList.InnerHtml))
        notificationsList.Visible = true;
```

it IS hitting the line notificationsList.Visible = true; but for whatever strange reason, the <ul> is still not visible.  I've stepped through this and I don't see any reason why such as other code conflicting, etc.

Here's the full method that is last to be called in Page_Load:

```
private void SetAndShowNotifications()
{
    notifications.Visible = false;

    SetItemRemovedNotification();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationsList.InnerHtml))
        notificationsList.Visible = true;
}
```

I just can't see it by stepping through as to why the hell this would not stick!

Comment: Does the ul show up within the div in the HTML?

Comment: No, but I know I have set it to visible before in another part of code (another method that runs in Page_Load) and it worked just fine.

Comment: I debugged, and even though it hits the line notificationsList.Visible = true; when I mouse over the Visible after it passes that line, it's still set to false...I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're setting the div's Visible to false and trying to set its child element's Visible to true...

```
notifications.Visible = false;
...
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationsList.InnerHtml))
   notificationsList.Visible = true;
```

Try replacing *notifications.Visible = false* with *notificationsList.Visible = false*.

Comment: Ok, it's time for coffee, duh.

Comment: totally forgot about that I had that div with a runat="server".  I need a vacation.

Comment: Intellisense doesn't always save time... :)

Answer (score 1):

You're hiding the "notifications" div on this line:

```
notifications.Visible = false;
```

Then trying to show the "notificationsList" ul afterwards:

```
notificationsList.Visible = true;
```

As long as the "notifications" div is hidden, it doesn't matter whether your "notificationsList" is visible or not since it's a child element. Change the logic inside the if statement to look like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationsList.InnerHtml))
{
    notifications.Visible = true;
    notificationsList.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where do you set the visibility. Here's a working example with a link button which shows the `ul` when the link is clicked:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    protected void ShowClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notificationsList.Visible = true;
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="notifications" class="notificationsContainer" runat="server">
        <ul id="notificationsList" visible="false" runat="server">Hello</ul>
    </div>    
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show" OnClick="ShowClick" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is set as part of a method call that happens in Page_Load and is the last set of code called in Page_Load so it should be fine!

Comment: The fact that when I mouseover Visible right after it clearly hit that line to set it to true and Visible is showing false STILL in the watch window after I pass that line of code, makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

At which point in the page life cycle are you trying to run this code? You should be doing this within OnPreRender, or even page load. Also if the UL isn't working why don't you switch it out for a placeholder which doesn't produce any markup and up would you the same result.

Comment: I run it at the end of PageLoad

Comment: The UL is working, and has worked in the past with other messages.  Plus it's very slick.  All I have to do is append a nice <li> to it from code-behind wherever I want.

Comment: Anyway that's much how jQuery does things in a lot of plug-ins using a list without any items and all you do is just add <li> elements to it and I love that way of handling messages also so I decided to do this in my OOP and Love that way of handling it.

Comment: It's probably the same way ValidationList works in ASP.NET anyway.